# Docker: How do I pull a specific build-id?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I would like to always pull a specific version, rather than just the latest.

A random example: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/aespinosa/jenkins/builds_history/9511/

I am doing this because I only want to deploy versions that I have audited. Is this currently possible? Or am I forced to fork them and make my own?

Comment: not sure if this will work, but have you tried `docker pull <your build id>`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can pull a specific [image by digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#/pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) by using the following syntax:

```
docker pull ubuntu@sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2
```

If you need to find the hash, it is output when pushing/pulling the image.  Some automated builds output it at the end.  I tried looking for the hash with `docker inspect` but it didn't appear to be there, so you'll have to delete the image and pull it again to view the hash.

Comment: Using docker ce 17.05, I'm able to retrieve digest from local image: `docker images --digest`

Comment: or `docker image inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE` for a specific image

Comment: For docker 20.10: `docker inspect --format='{{.Image}}' $IMAGE`

Answer (score 6):

The way I do it is to tag each build

```
docker build -t $NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$BUILD_SHA1 .
docker tag \
    $NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$SHA1 \
    $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$SHA1
docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$SHA1
```

and then you pull the specific tag

```
docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$SHA1
```

Comment: So looks like I'll have to keep a fork of my own

Comment: But tags are not immutable, how is this secure without immutability?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Joel's answer, you might want to verify the image exists on a specific Docker repo before trying to pull the image. The easiest way I know is using the Docker registry API. Make a simple HTTP GET request. Assemble the string like this -

```
FullURL = DomainAndPort + "/v2/" + imageName + "/blobs/sha256:" + imageHash;
```

An example request that works for me on our network repo -
http://10.10.9.84:5000/v2/hello-world/blobs/sha256:8089101ead9ce9b8c68d6859995c98108e1022c23beaa55754acb89d66fd3381

Entering that string into a Chrome browser returns a JSON object describing the image. If you enter an invalid sha256 hash then the API returns -

```
{"errors":[{"code":"DIGEST_INVALID","message":"provided digest did not match uploaded content","detail":{}}]}
```

For more details see "Pulling a Layer" in https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/