# Docker Hub: How do I pull an older version of a 3rd party image?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

How do I pull an older build of a 3rd party image from Docker Hub?

For example I would like to pull [this build](https://hub.docker.com/r/appropriate/curl/builds/b4f8nqnmaypvwmshyvzcesk/) of appropriate/curl.

I've tried using the "Build Code" as the tag, as well as the partial SHA256 of the image shown at the end of the build, and neither work.

Note: this is different from [Docker: How do I pull a specific build-id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445318/docker-how-do-i-pull-a-specific-build-id) since the author of that question is able to fork the version and tag their own builds as a workaround. I'm trying to access something that was built in the past (to analyze a regression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it's not possible. Build Details tab shows no tags other than latest and edge, which were overwritten each time a build was made.

Try to contact the image contributor. This is his github profile, where you can find his email address: https://github.com/md5

He might provide you a previous version taken from some of his old commits.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation.
Docker is the PHP of infrastructure :(

Comment: Actually this response is not correct, as Chris Stryczynski correctly pointed out.
And as an extra: I made the experiment of replacing a tagged image by a new one, and the digest ID continues to work (at least for the short term)

Answer (score 26):

You need the digest ID.

For example:

```
docker pull postgres@sha256:500edc08fa825dbf3f28dceced99fe84b8a4211d7a45fc0062250d4efb0f64c5
```

Some of the projects may have additional history available to retrieve an old digest id. For example these projects: https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/tree/master/repos

Answer (score 3):

You can use the digest ID only if the image doesn't have a tag. FROM is either `FROM image:tag` or `FROM image:hash`. This is just really bad when you want to pull `debian:jessie@c856411d1c21111855a54c5d29f2bfe099d63ce7`

Comment: This is not true. And it makes no sense to write `debian:jessie@c856411d1c21111855a54c5d29f2bfe099d63ce7`, it should be `debian@sha256:c856411d1c21111855a54c5d29f2bfe099d63ce7`. The tag does not matter when you already know its digest ID.